# How can i implement paypal checkout v2 server side / JS sdk

Tags: javascript, json, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, php-curl

I'm trying to make an implementation for paypal using checkout.js, however, i need to store the details of the transaction once the payment it's completed but first, i'm having trouble getting the button values from the server side, my code goes as follows:

````
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      // Order is created on the server and the order id is returned
      // Call your server to set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('php/create.php', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                return orderData.id;
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // Call your server to save the transaction
            return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete.php', {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID: details.id
              })
            });
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>```
````

```
<?php session_start();

// PayPal configuration
define('PAYPAL_CONFIG', [
    'URL' => "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/",
    'CLIENT_ID' => 'xxx',
    'SECRET' => 'xxx',
]);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, PAYPAL_CONFIG['URL'] . "v2/checkout/orders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PAYPAL_CONFIG['CLIENT_ID'] . ":" . PAYPAL_CONFIG['SECRET']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = [
    "intent" => "sale",
    "redirect_urls" => [
        "return_url" => "http://localhost:8888/index.php",
        "cancel_url" => "http://localhost:8888/index.php"
    ],
    "payer" => [
        "payment_method" => "paypal"
    ],
    "transactions" => [
        [
            "amount" => [
                "total" => $_SESSION['price'],
                "currency" => "USD"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);



$result = json_decode($response, true);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    error_log("Invalid JSON response: " . json_last_error_msg());
    var_dump($httpStatusCode);
    return false;
}

if (!$result) {
    error_log("cURL request failed with HTTP status code: " . $httpStatusCode);
    var_dump($httpStatusCode);
    return false;
}

return $result;
```

Whenever i try to click the paypal button, i keep getting a console error saying that Error: Unexpected end of Json input and closes the paypal window almost immediately

I've tried debbuging with several methods but i can't get it working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

(That code is not for [checkout.js](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout-v4/) , which is older and deprecated ; you're using the current [PayPal JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server))

Anyway, this issue:

> Error: Unexpected end of Json input

Occurs when your server-side code is outputting something other than a purse JSON string, such as a var_dump or other echo statement. Your create and capture routes must output *only* a JSON string, never any other text or HTML.

You can get a log of the response being outputted to the XHR request in your browser's dev tools -> Network tab.